# How to create AVD that represent Samsung Galaxy S in Eclipse emulator?

Tags: android

I am working on an application specifically for Samsung Galaxy S(I am not the one making decision here) and they want its layout to be pixel-precise accurate.
Can I just use normal 2.1 AVD?

So I tried creating WQVGA432 but it looks like this. I'm not sure why the LinearLayout does not fill up the screen but only use up to the large images with Korean (which I can't scale down, but that's different question).

[image: WQVGA432]

This is main.xml:

> ```
> <RelativeLayout 
>     android:id="@+id/ui_navBar"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="#FF333333"
>
>     <!-- This is navigation panel at the top of the page -->
>     <!-- Top-Left Button, aka Back button -->
>     <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/ui_topLeftBox"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true">
>     </FrameLayout>
> ```

```
    <!-- Screen name -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/ui_topBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Top-Right Button, aka Forward button -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/ui_topRightBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ui_contentView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:paddingTop="0px" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <!-- Main View --> 
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/topBanner"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#FFFFCC00"
            >
            <TextView android:textSize="20sp" 
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:text="EUR/USD"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topBanner"
            android:background="#FF444444">
            <CheckBox android:id="@+id/cbx1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
            <com.vg.library.NumericInput 
                android:id="@+id/val1Nip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cbx1"
                 />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <com.vg.library.NumericInput 
            android:id="@+id/val2Nip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view1" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Screen01"
            android:layout_below="@+id/val2Nip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<!-- ExpandBar -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/ui_expandBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bar"
        android:background="#0000"
    />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ui_drawerView"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="0px" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ui_expandBar">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ui_drawerContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF550000" >
            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/m1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF550000" >
            <CheckBox android:id="@+id/cbxB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
            <com.vg.library.NumericInput 
                android:id="@+id/valBNip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cbxB"
                 />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF333333"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    >
    <!-- This is menu panel at the bottom of the page -->
    <com.vg.library.MenuBar 
        android:id="@+id/ui_menuBar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#FFAAAA00"
        >
        <!-- All menu item should go here -->
    </com.vg.library.MenuBar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, set the screen resolution to wqvga (800 * 432).

Comment: Thank you :)
but it looks kinda strange.
This is how it look, the root of the XML is LinearLayout with FILL_PARENT for width and height. I also set the background color to red.
http://i137.photobucket.com/albums/q219/RobGThai/wqvga432.png

Comment: @RobGThai Did you find a solution for this problem? I had just begun working on an Android device and I'm up against this oddity.

Answer (score 1):

Galaxy S has this Display:

- Super AMOLED (C-type) display
- WVGA (800 x 480) Sub display resolution
- 4.0" Sub display size
- 16M Main display colour depth

More specifications at http://developer.samsung.com/deviceSpecs/deviceView.do?menu=EN01030100&dvceId=47#

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/topBanner"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#FFFFCC00"
            >
```

for your application