# Android AVD For Specific Device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I created an Android application that I have published in the marketplace.  It crashes on a specific device, the Motorola Cliq XT, so I would like to make an AVD of this device and test it in the emulator.  I know that I can make a new AVD with the right API level, but what other considerations are there for this AVD so that I can closely mimic the actual device?  Are there standard AVDs that someone has released for different phones, or do we not have that kind of flexibility?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Motorola Developer Network site provides [instructions for downloading and installing](http://www.motorola.com/sites/motodev/SDK_Addons/installation.html) the necessary add-ons to support the creation of a device-specific AVD.  Sadly, I'm no longer able to find the actual download page.

Comment: Thanks.  Are there similar sites for other Android phones?

Comment: I'd imagine that each of the manufactures would have equivalent downloads, but I don't know of them.  The HTC developer site seems to have kernel sources, but not much else - http://developer.htc.com/

Comment: I also found a page for the [Samsung Galaxy Tab](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do), but not one for the Galaxy S phones.  If you ever find ones for those, please add an answer to one of these SO questions: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307621/how-to-create-avd-that-represent-samsung-galaxy-s-in-eclipse-emulator) or [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177556/android-samsung-galaxy-s-emulator)

Comment: @MattPassell Motorola seems to have redesigned their developer site since your answer was posted. Any idea where to get the device-specific stuff now?

Comment: @HolisticDeveloper I've edited my answer to link to the new location for the instructions page. As I say in the answer, I was unable to find the new location of the downloads page. What a broken site! :(

Comment: @MattPassell thanks for trying. I did find that link yesterday after doing some searching -- it definitely seems to be a hold over from the old site. Too bad.